# IDA sdk delete user struct member prevent creating gap

Tags: ida, c++

I have a problem using IDA SDK function `del_struc_member(struc_t *sptr, ea_t offset)` ,

If i use it on a member, it creates a gap[4] on the offset ( for dword type), it doesn't recalc the struct and it doesn't shrink it.

If i use another function from SDK, `expand_struc(struc_t *sptr, ea_t offset, adiff_t delta, bool recalc=true);` like so `expand_struc(struc, 4, -4, true)`;

It does delete the member and shrink it, but it deletes other gap's that goes after (that are needed)plus it change the type of other members , for example:

*before*:

```
  int field_1204;
  _BYTE gap4B8[4];
  int field_1212;
```

*after*:

```
  int field_1204;
  __declspec(align(8)) int field_1212;
```

If i delete member manually by CTRL+E, it does shrink and doesn't create this problems with removing gap's.

What is correct way of removing a struct member and shrinking it ?
P.S.
Maybe i should set new type for all other gap's that are correct and only after that remove the member i don't need and shrink the struct . Or it would create same problems if its array ?